# Joomla 3.3.1 SEF Multilanguage menu item URL throw 404

Tags: php, joomla, http-status-code-404, categories, joomla-sef-urls

### Languages

- en-GB
- zh-CN

### Menu

- menu-en-gb

  - Company

    - Jobs *(menu-item)*  <-- LOOK AT THIS
- menu-zh-cn

#### Jobs menu-item settings

- **Alias**: `jobs`
- **Menu Item Type**: `Category List`
- **Choose a category**: `Jobs`
- **Language**: `English (UK)`

### Problem

When I visit http://example.com/en/jobs, it throws 404

[image: Category page throws 404]

I have enabled `mod_rewrite` and renamed `htaccess.txt` to `.htaccess`.

I've tried to add a statement to my template **index.php**

```
<?php
die('die here');
```

in a very first statement.

By the way, I'm using custom template here.

Does anyone face the same problem?

**Edit**

It is not only for category listing, as long as is from that particular menu, then throw 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem after struggling for a day.

**Solution**

`Jobs` is a submenu-item under `Company`, thus the URL should be http://example.com/en/company/jobs instead of just http://example.com/en/jobs without a `company`

If want to achieve the URL without `company`

1. Create a new Menu *(hidden menu)*, then add a new menu-item called `Jobs` with alias `jobs`.
2. Go to the `menu-en-gb` -> `Jobs`, set the **Menu Item Type** to `System Links` -> `Menu Item Alias`
3. Select the **Menu Item** to the menu-item just created in the hidden menu

Done